# Regular Expression between strings (multiple results?)

Tags: regex, sed

I am using a regular expression to filter a link from a HTML page like so:

```
(?<=data-ng-non-bindable data-src=\")(.*?)(?=\" data-caption)
```

How do I change it so that I get multiple results, not only the first one?

Comment: Different libraries and languages work differently. You'll need to explain which you're using.

Comment: Hey, sorry for that, im not quite sure how i want to accomplish this: I download a website html (wget http://... ) then i want to use sed to cut everything out, except everything with this regular expression above. 
The System i am using is a debian. Does that help?
As you can tell my knowledge is pretty basic... :/

Comment: I also realized, that my plan to use sed to cut everything out of this downloaded file except these links does not work... this is how i tried it:
sed -i '/(?<=data-ng-non-bindable data-src=\")(.*?)(?=\" data-caption)/g' file.txt

Comment: Answer to myself: sed cannot do positive lookahead. Indead i used perl: 
grep -oP '(?<=data-ng-non-bindable data-src=\")(.*?)(?=\" data-caption)'
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, you **replace** strings, not **extract**. There are options you may set to actually output replaced substrings only, there is always a big problem with matches on the the same line.

Due to this, the easiest will be using `grep` with `-oP` options:

```
grep -oP '(?<=data-ng-non-bindable data-src=").*?(?=" data-caption)' file > outfile
```

Double quotation marks are not special.